# What is the correct way to update a value to be NULL on a Magento model?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am having an issue getting a custom model's value to update to NULL.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('custom/model')->load($id);
$model->setCustomValue(NULL);
$model->save();
```

This code does not update the field `custom_value` in the database, and the database value accepts NULL values (Manually setting NULL in the database works fine).

**EDIT:**
As Tim mentions below using `Zend_Db_Expr("NULL")` does set the value to null, could anyone explain why this is required in Magento and not just simply a php `NULL` ?

Comment: just try $model->setCustomValue("");

Comment: The type of the table field is `double` and I have tried other numeric types like `decimal` and doing `$model->setCustomValue("");` sets the value to `0`

Comment: How about `$null = new Zend_Db_Expr("NULL");` ?

Comment: @Invoke, to reply to your answer, if you only set it to "NULL" Magento will only think you don't want to update the value. As Tim suggested, you need to specify that it's the database "NULL" that you want to set.

Comment: Thanks @mayers-dev, interesting behaviour. I guess it was designed as a get-out-clause should you need to cancel the intended update while generating the value itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, as so often a `isset()` vs `array_key_exists()` problem, when I see this correctly.

I didn't try it, but from code reading I would say, the value is checked here:

```
\Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_saveAttribute
if (!isset($this->_attributeValuesToSave[$table])) {
    $this->_attributeValuesToSave[$table] = array();
}
```

and because `isset` return false on a set array key which is `NULL`, your value is overwritten.